Newton method for polynomials with random starting points
I know that this question exists, but unfortunately it doesn't cover my issue sufficiently.
Assume that we have a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$ with real coefficients, we can assume that all its coefficients are known (if we need it for estimates). If it makes things simpler, we may assume that $n=4$, but a generic answer is also of interest.

For some constant $C$, we pick the starting point $x+iy$ uniformly at random such that $\max(|x|, |y|) \leq C$. For a large enough $C$, can we guarantee that the convergence will be with high probability?
Would it be better if, instead, we picked a starting point uniformly at random from the circle $x^2+y^2 = C$?
Are there known estimates on the number of iterations it would take to enter the area of quadratic convergence?
Are there any other "simple" regions, s.t. picking the starting point in them increases convergence likelyhood?

I know that there are certain grids that provably guarantee that a root will be found in a small number of iterations, but I'm currently interested in the properties of picking the starting point at random, rather than from a proven grid.

I know the references for question 4:
MR3659421 Schleicher, Dierk; Stoll, Robin Newton's method in practice: Finding all roots of polynomials of degree one million efficiently. Theoret. Comput. Sci. 681 (2017), 146–166.
MR4623931 Randig, Marvin; Schleicher, Dierk; Stoll, Robin Newton's method in practice, II: The iterated refinement Newton method and near-optimal complexity for finding all roots of some polynomials of very large degrees. J. Comput. Appl. Math. 437 (2024), Paper No. 115427;
These papers contain references to other papers of Schleicher and his collaborators
on this question.
I suppose that the answers to 1,2,3 is negative, since you do not specify how $C$ is related to your original polynomial.

Re: How $C$ is related to polynomial: This is a part of the question, whether there is a meaningful way to choose $C$, based on the polynomial, so that some bound exists.
Re: Question 4: Could you please elaborate a bit on which pages are you referring to? I briefly skimmed them, but I feel like they're concerned with constructing a grid that guarantees finding all roots, rather than constructing a simple geometric shape and sampling starting points randomly inside of it?

If you are interested in Newton's method you should read these papers carefully. The starting set that they provide is essentially $|z|>C$ where $C$ depends on the polynomial.
